# External list with hyperlinks sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, external-content-type, external-list

How do I make a column (content) a hyperlink with an external list in SharePoint 2013? I have the url in the database and need to turn it into a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

In SP2013 you can use CSR - Client Side Rendering to change the display and add HTML around the url.

You could try adding a Calculated Column with Formula:

```
   ="<a href='" & url & "'>" & Title & "</a>"
```

and set the datatype to Number

This will output as HTML... But only on ListViews!  Then again it works in 2010 as well.

Comment: I have the html in there but it's just coming across as plain text rather than a hyperlink <a href="https://sitename.domain.com/employees/SitePages/Employee%20Experience.aspx?domain\username"> View Experience </a>

Comment: set to datatype=Number, and is it a ListView webpart..